# How To Define Masters In A New Presentation With Google Slides API?

Tags: android, google-slides-api

I am building an Android app that programmatically creates a presentation.  I've tried using both the Java libraries as well as the online interactive slides API to create a new presentation and set the master slides.  I am starting simple here - all I want to do is have a solid blue background master slide.  Here is my API call to create:

```
{
  "title": "test",
  "masters": [
    {
      "pageProperties": {
        "pageBackgroundFill": {
          "solidFill": {
            "color": {
              "rgbColor": {
                "blue": 1.0,
                "green": 0.5,
                "red": 1.0
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "pageType": "MASTER",
      "masterProperties": {
        "displayName": "mymaster"
      },
      "objectId": "mymaster1"
    }
  ]
}
```

Result is 200 OK.  I look at the data in the result and my master is not there.  The default master is there however.  This is maddening - I have been searching for days on this.  I must be missing some required fields - but this is not documented well by Google.  I'd greatly appreciate some guidance on this.

Here is my Java code:

```
// Build master -
        List<Page> master = new ArrayList<>();
        master.add(new Page().setPageProperties(new PageProperties().setPageBackgroundFill(new PageBackgroundFill()
                .setSolidFill(new SolidFill().setColor(new OpaqueColor()
                .setRgbColor(new RgbColor().setRed(1.0f).setGreen(0.5f).setBlue(1.0f))))))
                                        .setPageType("MASTER").setObjectId("mymaster1").setMasterProperties(new MasterProperties().setDisplayName("mymaster")));

        // Create presentation
        Presentation presentation = new Presentation()
                .setTitle("test").setMasters(master);
        presentation = mSlidesService.presentations().create(presentation)
                .setFields("presentationId")
                .execute();
```

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

The official documentation is misleading, showing all the fields in the request body.

It says:

> If a presentationId is provided, it is used as the ID of the new presentation. Otherwise, a new ID is generated. **Other fields in the request**, including any provided content, **are ignored**. Returns the created presentation.

So, only the `title` and the `presentationId` are used.
Use `batchUpdate()` right after creation of the presentation.

https://developers.google.com/slides/api/reference/rest/v1/presentations/create